# STM32 and SP value at startup: should the reset handler set SP manually?

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, cortex-m, stack-pointer

I am experiencing a sporadic bug on some STM32F7s. While usually SP register takes its initial value from reset vector (stored in persistent read-only memory), sometimes it is initially set to an apparently random value.

I discovered that someone probably faced a similar problem, because some sample programs look like:

```
void __attribute__((naked, noreturn)) Reset_Handler()
{
    //Normally the CPU should will setup the based on the value from the first entry in the vector table.
    //If you encounter problems with accessing stack variables during initialization, ensure the line below is enabled.
    #ifdef sram_layout
    asm ("ldr sp, =_estack");
    #endif
```

By adding `asm ("ldr sp, =_estack")` the problem seems to disappear, but I can't find any documentation about this issue (except the samples I've just cited). My concern is that the "solution" just hides a deeper problem that is waiting the worst moment to happen.

So, is it a known problem? Are there specific documents or errata about this issue?

Comment: Just a guess: reset handler can take control not only after reset but after jump as well, e.g. from bootloader.

Comment: (+1) Interesting. A way to observe this phenomenon quite often is in fact to load a new firmware by JTAG. I thought that the programming program would eventually issue a reset via JTAG's reset line, but maybe it doesn't (I never checked), and the loader just jumps to reset handler without loading SP properly.

Comment: @dimich : In my opinion, your post is eligible as real answer to my question (and I would accept it)

Comment: @dimich: I've just verified that my programmer issues a hardware reset after programming. Uhm...

Comment: JTAG may issue a reset, but then things can reset again.  The STM32CubeIDE generates this as the first startup instruction `ldr   r0, =_estack`.  It can be that the vector table copy is not valid.  Ie, the flash is in a program state on reset or all sorts of craziness.  Why don't you just leave the `ldr   r0, =_estack`?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini I haven't analyzed this topic deeply but came across some related topics, e.g.  [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BuecYaSQI/stack-pointer-value-at-boot-time), [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000AnrwAnSQI/stack-pointer-initialization) and [here](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/architectures-and-processors-forum/13195/beginner-question-stack-pointer-initialization). Not sure if it's related to your observations of random SP value.